# AspNetCore MVC Package Resolve RC2

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Just updated to AspNetCore and having issues with the client side still referencing the ASPNET MVC packages, such as:

`"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "1.0.0-*"`

They no longer exist in my package directory or have a reference in the project json and have been replaced by their new namespaces such as:

`"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor": "1.0.0-*"`

I also deleted and regenerated the lock file. Getting errors like Razor does not exist in the namespace Micosoft.AspNet.Mvcand IUrlHelper etc. I also ran the new dotnet commands with no luck.

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "define": [ "DEMO", "TESTING" ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.WebListener": "0.1.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "1.0.0-*",   
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-*",
    "Autofac": "4.0.0-*",
    "Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "4.0.0-*", 
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "8.0.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.Elm": "0.1.0-rc2-16612",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core": "1.0.0-*",
    "WindowsAzure.Storage": "6.2.2-preview",
    "System.Linq.Parallel": "4.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc2-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-*",
    "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching": "2.7.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations": "1.0.0-*",  
    "Google.Apis.Oauth2.v2": "1.10.0.1050",
    "Google.Apis.Gmail.v1": "1.9.2.340",
    "Google.Apis": "1.10.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0-rc2-*",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms": "1.0.1-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session": "1.0.0-rc2-*"
  },
  "commands": {
    "web": "makeithappen"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Web": "4.0.0.0"
      }  
    }

  },
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
     "node_modules",
      "bower_components",
      "dist",
      ".tmp"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc",
    "*.cmd"
  ],
  "scripts": {
        "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
    }
```

Comment: Try using https://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/ to find which packages you need. Right now it's a bit awkward and requires some trial and error.

Comment: The packages resolve successfully server side.

Comment: Hmm. Sounds like something is still referencing those packages. If you've removed *everything* that references `Microsoft.AspNet`, you shouldn't be getting errors about that namespace. Can you post your project.json?

Comment: Are you using any third party packages that has not been updated to use .AspNetCore. and may pull in .AspNet. versions of packages?

Comment: at the top of **Solution Explorer** window in Visual Studio 2015, there is a text box for **Search Solution Explorer**, enter `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` there and hopefully you can find which package is referring to them.

Comment: yep this found a bunch of AspNet.Mvc in the bin which I deleted, however, still same issue until I ran the DotNet Restore command on the top level of the solution which has caused a bunch of MVC dependency issues which is a good thing. Will update this once resolved. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Controller and view component discovery was broken.

"As part of our recent migration, we broke compatibility with DNX in Mvc"

Visit https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/154